# Stop Firefox from autocompleting addresses

Tags: firefox

I'm a webdeveloper, trying to switch from Chrome to Firefox, but there's one thing driving me nuts:

I run a local development server, which I access through the browser at the regular `localhost` URL. As you may understand, different projects, have different URLs, so my browsing history for the localhost domain is most of the time invalid for my current needs.

Now on to the real problem: whenever I type `localhost:<port>` in the location bar and press `<Enter>` Firefox autocompletes this address (AFTER pressing `<Enter>`) to some old URL from a previous project, which of course 404s for my current project... How can I stop this?

Some info about my Firefox installation:

- I just updated like, 10 minutes ago, so I'm running the latest stable version.
- I only have one plugin installed at this time (vimperator), but the problem existed before installing it, so I'm pretty sure it has nothing to do with it.
- I disabled all suggestions (open tabs, history, and bookmarks).
- I set **browser.urlbar.autocomplete.enabled** to **False**.
- I set **browser.urlbar.autoFill** to **False**.

So I get **no** suggestions while typing an address, but once I hit `<Enter>` Firefox simply appends history stuff to the address I entered.

It might be that I'm simply missing something trivial, I haven't used Firefox in a long time so there's that.

Any suggestions? :)

Answer (score 0):

Just hotfix, try to delete invalid url from history. Just type what you want and instead of pressing enter, press down arrow to select some "advised" old url and than pres delete.